# Correct verb to describe relationships between processes in technical writing

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, technical

I am writing a thesis, and the tone of my writing is technical. At a few places, I need a specific verb to describe how a particular process/method/technique relates to another process/method/technique.  For example, a particular process only focuses on one aspect of a second process but not other aspects of that process. I find it hard to express this.

For example, I want to say:

> "the dependence computation process **concerns** only the connectivity relationship among nodes"

but I feel that "concerns" sound like a human word; it is weird to say that a process/method/technique "concerns" something.

I could replace the word with "cares", "is interested in", but still it looks weird.

#### Edit:

Let me clarify a bit: "concerns"/"cares"/"is interested in" are words that seem to anthropomorphize the process/method/technique. So I'm looking for a verb which describes the same meaning but can be used by inanimate objects.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just as I might suggest changing "human word" to "a word that 'relates' [primarily] to humans" in your question, maybe you could replace 'concerns' with 'relates' in your example..

Comment: @JimReynolds I think there are some subtle differences. It's more appropriate to use "applies only to" to the domain in which the method is used. But here I want to focus on the method itself (e.g. the method has only one target to aim and not anything else).

Comment: [***Quantum physics concerns itself with** the study of the constituent elements of nature which are divided into discrete units or packets of energy called “quanta.”*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EbSuDtaOH_cC&pg=PA54&dq=%22quantum+physics+concerns%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YmcdVdPIB876aoPVgfgB&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22quantum%20physics%20concerns%22&f=false) You're completely mistaken if you suppose there's anything "incorrect" about such usages. But it's true that in more "formal" contexts many people wouldn't like to see similar usages involving ***to care, to be interested in***.

Comment: As above, the better question might be if an anthropomorphization is *weird* to typical English readers, or only to you. In fact, you wrote "it looks weird". Do you mean that "it" has sight? Weird!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your could use instead:

*"the dependence computation process **is /related/connected/** only **to** the connectivity relationship among nodes"*

*"the dependence computation process **/involves/implicates/** only the connectivity relationship among nodes"*

*"the dependence computation process **touches only on** the connectivity relationship among nodes"* [weaker and fuzzier]

but **"concerns" is correct**
as shown by these edited (one hopes!) and published examples at Google Books:

[**"computation concerns only"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22his%20intent%20were%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22computation%20concerns%20only%22)
About 29 results

E.g., surely this is a native speaker:

> The Economics of Enterprise - Page 69
>
> Herbert Joseph Davenport - 1919 - ‎Snippet view - ‎More editions
>
> **The cost computation concerns only the** future supply.

Comment: Do you mean that the sentence structure of "<inanimate object> concerns <another inanimate object>" is actually correct?

Comment: @Erencie see my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

"the dependence computation process *[isolates](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/isolate)* the connectivity relationship among nodes":

> 1.1 Identify (something) and examine or deal with it separately:
>
> ODO

Answer (score 1):

"Targets only the" or "focuses on only the/focuses only on the" would perhaps not contain the humanistic value that you see in "concerns."

Answer (score 0):

> . . . [C]oncerns itself only with . . . .

Or perhaps

> . . . applies only to . . . .
>
> . . . relates only to . . . .

Answer (score 0):

> As a verb, concern means to be [relevant to something](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/concern?family=concerns).
>
> Similar words:  pertain, refer, relate, touch, touch on

*Focus only on one aspect of things but not the other*

> "the dependence computation process **is limited to** the
> connectivity relationship among nodes".
>
> "the dependence computation process **is associated with** the
> connectivity relationship among nodes".

```
Associated- make a logical or causal connection (vocabulary.com)
```